# when i tried to put two forms at the seem time i cant i don't know why everything is good and true

Tags: python, django

ValueError at /update_profile/

The Profile could not be changed because the data didn't validate.

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/update_profile/
Django Version:     3.0.5
Exception Type:     ValueError
Exception Value:

The Profile could not be changed because the data didn't validate.

Exception Location:     D:\project_4\my_project\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py in save, line 454
Python Executable:  D:\project_4\my_project\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version:     3.7.6
Python Path:

['C:\Users\pc\Desktop\template\project_4\my_project\src\project',
 'D:\project_4\my_project\Scripts\python37.zip',
 'c:\users\pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\DLLs',
 'c:\users\pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib',
 'c:\users\pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32',
 'D:\project_4\my_project',
 'D:\project_4\my_project\lib\site-packages']

Server time:    Sat, 16 May 2020 14:51:34 +0000
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view

```
D:\project_4\my_project\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py in inner

                response = get_response(request)

     …
▶ Local vars
D:\project_4\my_project\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in _get_response

                    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

     …
▶ Local vars
D:\project_4\my_project\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in _get_response

                    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

     …
▶ Local vars
D:\project_4\my_project\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py in _wrapped_view

                    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

     …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\pc\Desktop\template\project_4\my_project\src\project\accounts\views.py in update_profile

                profile_form.save()

     …
▶ Local vars
D:\project_4\my_project\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py in save

                        'created' if self.instance._state.adding else 'changed',

     …
▶ Local vars
```

and this is my view :

```
@login_required()
def update_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UpdateUserForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        profile_form = UpdateProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)
        if user_form.is_valid and profile_form.is_valid:
            user_form.save()
            profile_form.save()
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        user_form = UpdateUserForm(instance=request.user)
        profile_form = UpdateProfileForm(instance=request.user.profile)

    context = {
        'user_form': user_form,
        'profile_form': profile_form,
    }
    return render(request, 'Update_profile.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `is_valid()` method in your views.py file. Add parentheses to avoid wrong validation. If you forget them, python gets the function which is considered as a True value.